# What happens when I reassign a frequently accessed class field to a new object?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I have a class like this:

```
class Test {

    const int capacity = 100_0000;

    private HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(capacity);

    public Test() { this.Reassign(); }

    private void Reassign() {
        var thread = new Thread(() => {
            while (true) {
                set = new HashSet<int>(capacity);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        });
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Add(int val) {
        set.Add(val);
    }

}
```

The add method is frequently called.

```
var test = new Test();

Task.Run(() => {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        test.Add(i);
        Thread.SpinWait(5000);
    }
});
```

It doesn't matter whether the data is successfully stored in the set, in this case, is the behavior of the add method consistent with the following code?

```
class LockTest {

    const int capacity = 100_0000;

    private HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(capacity);

    public LockTest() { this.Reassign(); }

    private void Reassign() {
        var thread = new Thread(() => {
            while (true) {
                lock (set) set = new HashSet<int>(capacity);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        });
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Add(int val) {
        lock (set) set.Add(val);
    }

}
```

In my tests, even if there is no lock statement, there is no error. But I don't know what happens at the moment of `set = new HashSet<int>(capacity);`.

Comment: _"But I don't know what happens at the moment of set = new HashSet<int>(capacity);"_ - in what context? In terms of threading? HashSet _is_ a reference type.

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent with"? If you mean "has an unpredictable result because I don't know which set instance I added the value to", then sure, it should be consistent. Don't know why you want that feature though. Can you elaborate on the usecase of this scenario?

Comment: The way I read it is that you are locking one object, but then assigning it to a new instance, therefore, only sometimes will the lock actually do what you want it to do.

Comment: If you have 1 thread replacing the set references, and 1 thread adding an item to the "current" set, then you should have no problems with the sets themselves. The unpredictability is that you have lost control over *which* set you add to.

Comment: And please understand that the concept of "thread safety" is not a concept that has a fixed answer. You need to explain to us what you hope this introduction of a lock should do, because I don't think it does what you think it does.

Comment: It won't crash or corrupt state.  The program relies on the .NET memory model providing the guarantee that object reference updates are *atomic*.  Another thread can't observe a partially written value for the reference.  So the hashset reference is always valid and usable, you just don't know which one it will be.  Never assume that atomicity is equivalent to locking.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, your comments solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the code to this, what do you think will happen?  My guess is that the number you print out will sometimes be the same and other time different.  When it is the same, lock(set) has worked, but otherwise it hasn't.

```
class LockTest {

const int capacity = 100_0000;

private int setCnt = 0;
private object set = new object();

public LockTest() { this.Reassign(); }

private void Reassign() {
    var thread = new Thread(() => {
        while (true) {
            lock (set) setCnt++;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    });
    thread.Start();
}

public void Add(int val) {
    lock (set) Console.WriteLine($"{setCnt}");
}
```

}